# How to calculate hours worked between 2 different days in SQL using CURSOR/PROC?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to calculate the number of hours an employee had worked from 21-Jan-2019 to 22-Jan-2019 starttime on the 21st is 21:00 and timeout on 22nd is 07:00 it should be 10hrs but its showing 14hrs.

```
create table babysitter (
babysitterid char(5) not null primary key,
datein date not null,
timein time not null,
dateout date not null,
timeout time not null, 
noofhrswrk int,
amtpaid int
);

insert into babysitter values('BS001', '18-Jan-2019', '10:00', '18-Jan-2019', '16:00', '', '')
insert into babysitter values('BS002', '15-Jan-2019', '13:00', '15-Jan-2019', '20:00', '', '')
insert into babysitter values('BS003', '21-Jan-2019', '21:00', '22-Jan-2019', '07:00', '', '')
insert into babysitter values('BS004', '11-Jan-2019', '08:00', '11-Jan-2019', '13:00', '', '')

declare @timein time
declare @timeout time
declare @hoursworked datetime

declare Calculate_No_Hrs cursor for 
select timein, timeout, noofhrswrk from babysitter

open Calculate_No_Hrs

fetch next from Calculate_No_Hrs into @timein, @timeout, @hoursworked

while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
update babysitter
set noofhrswrk = abs(datediff(hour, timeout, timein)) 

fetch next from Calculate_No_Hrs into @timein, @timeout, @hoursworked
end

close Calculate_No_Hrs
deallocate Calculate_No_Hrs
```

Comment: You forgot to include the create statement for the table... Also, if you could include the desired results it would be great.

Comment: @ZoharPeled i didnt include the create statement because its not important, and i did tell that i need the result to be 10hrs

Comment: It's not important to you, maybe, but if you want us to be able to test our answers before posting them, you should provide all the relevant data - and a part of that data is the ddl for the relevant table(s). Otherwise you might as well just post the sample data as text, not as insert statements (which would lead to requests for sample data as DDL+DML)

Comment: You have 2 mistakes: 1st: You do NOT include the DATE in your calculation. Then, the 2nd, getting "negative" values, you use ABS function to change the sign ... of a correct calculation: The difference between 0700 and 2100 is 14 hours .... but the wrong direction!

Comment: The solution is: create a Datetime from date AND time for timein and the same for timeout, and then use the datediff method.

Comment: @ZoharPeled updated

Comment: Why are you inserting blank strings in the columns that you declare as an `int`?

Comment: @nabuchodonossor yes correct it was showing -14hrs, for the date i  need to make use of a cursor thats why im storing them in variables `timein` and `timeout`.

Comment: Why do you need a cursor? A cursor is an awful way to do this. Treat your data as a data set, not as individual rows.

Comment: @Larnu because there're no initial values, the calculation is in the cursor, after the calculation the table should be updated to insert new values

Comment: @Larnu yes indeed but the assignment is about cursors and procedures

Comment: If you need to `UPDATE` the table you can change `SELECT` to `UPDATE babysitter SET noofhrswrk =`... in my answer, but there is no reason to do this as a cursor. A cursor should never be used for this type of operation, as it can be achieved using a set based process. Using one is just a bad idea and will cause (significant) performance problems. If someone is telling you to use a Cursor to achieve this, they are (quite simply) wrong to tell you so.

Comment: @Larnu i understand your point but its not about performance, the assignment told me to use a cursor or a procedure to do these questions, i cant use queries

Comment: Even to declare a cursor you need a query, @Cat_img.jpeg. SQL is a **Query** Language, you can't write it without using queries. By Procedure do you mean stored procedure? I could easily wrap the below in an SP, if that's the requirement but if this is your assignment then it should be you doing that, using my answer as a basis.

Comment: yes Stored Procedures

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to combine your time and date values and then get the difference:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE babysitter (ID char(5),
                         StartDate date,
                         StartTime time(0),
                         EndDate date,
                         EndTime time(0),
                         BlankCol1 char(1),
                         BlankCol2 char(1));

insert into babysitter values('BS001', '18-Jan-2019', '10:00', '18-Jan-2019', '16:00', '', '')
insert into babysitter values('BS002', '15-Jan-2019', '13:00', '15-Jan-2019', '20:00', '', '')
insert into babysitter values('BS003', '21-Jan-2019', '21:00', '22-Jan-2019', '07:00', '', '')
insert into babysitter values('BS004', '11-Jan-2019', '08:00', '11-Jan-2019', '13:00', '', '')
GO

SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR,V.StartTime, V.EndTime)
FROM dbo.babysitter
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES (DATEADD(SECOND,DATEDIFF(SECOND,0,StartTime),CONVERT(datetime2(0),StartDate)),
                          DATEADD(SECOND,DATEDIFF(SECOND,0,EndTime),CONVERT(datetime2(0),EndDate)))) V(StartTime, EndTime)


GO
DROP TABLE dbo.babysitter;
```

Comment: i need to use a cursor/procedure for that

Comment: For what @Cat_img.jpeg? What is "that"? You certainly don't need a cursor to achieve what you describe

Answer (score 0):

Try this - it is giving correct hours when combining date and time before calculating difference in hours

```
declare @in datetime, @out datetime

set @in = '21-Jan-2019 21:00' 
set @out = '22-Jan-2019 7:00'

select DATEDIFF(hh, @in, @out)
```